# Сравнение случайных чисел

Tags: java, случайные-числа

Здравствуйте.
 Цель: программа генерирующая два случайные числа из заданного диапазона, сравнивает их. Если не равны выводит сообщение:"Не равны, попытка №-Х" и загадывает новые целые числа. Это закончится когда Random-ные int-ы совпадут.

```
public class GonaNumber{
  public static void main(String[]args){
  String stars = (************);
  int numGuess = 0;// счетчик попыток
  //первое сравниваемое число
  int randomA = (int)(Math.random()*10+1);
  //второе сравниваемое число
  int randomB = (int)(Math.random()*10+1);
  System.out.println(stars);
  System.out.println("Загадываем числа для сравнения");
  System.out.println(stars);
  numGuess++;
  while(randomA != randomB){
    System.out.println("Хм не в этот раз... Попытка номер "+numGuess);
    numGuess++
  }
  System.out.println("Совпали на "+numGuess+" попытке");
}
```

Остановил компьютер на второй минуте запуска программы, потом осенило, я пять миллионов раз сравнил одни и те-же цифры.

Comment: А что требуется то? переписать имеющийся у вас код что бы работало?

Comment: Да, это моя цель. Прошу прощенье за не корректно заданный вопрос. "Новенький" что с меня взять ))

Comment: нет проблем. только дополните вопрос на всякий случай :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы сравниваете одни и те же числа, рандомьте в каждой итерации цикла.
Подобное должно работать.

```
public class GonaNumber{

  final Random random = new Random();

  public static void main(String[]args){

  String stars = (************);
  int numGuess = 1;// счетчик попыток
  System.out.println(stars);
  System.out.println("Загадываем числа для сравнения");
  System.out.println(stars);
  int randomA = 0;
  int randomB = 0; 
  while(true){
    //первое сравниваемое число
    randomA = random.nextInt();
    //второе сравниваемое число
    randomB = random.nextInt();
    if(randomA!=randomB){
     System.out.println("Хм не в этот раз... Попытка номер "+numGuess);
     numGuess++;
    }else{
     break;
    }
  }
  System.out.println("Совпали на "+numGuess+" попытке");
}
```

И не парьтесь вы с созданием целого числа из вещественного. у вас есть Random\ThreadLocalRandom и замечательный .nextInt(). никаких кастов, никаких *10+1, одно удовольствие.

Comment: Не работает. Требует обьявить переменные еще до while, а потом ругается на то что переменные повторяются:  -Duplicate local variable

Comment: @CoffeJava обновил. спросонья ерунду какую то вам отослал, не серчайте.

Comment: Не серчаю. Подогнал своё под ваш код, в результате прога запустилась но ... я так понимаю, что предела цифрам нет? уже 11 миллионов раз сравнил и всё мимо.

Comment: @CoffeJava по идее мы получаем рандомное число в пределах int, а это, если мне не изменяет память от -2147483648 до 2147483647, т.е. шанс совпадения не слишком большой, для чистоты эксперимента попробуйте сделать nextInt(20), таким образом вы будете получать числа от 0 до 20. Должно проявиться быстрее.

Comment: Гут Виктор , спасибо, заработало. Совпадают на 7 , 20 , 41 попытках.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в тело цикла `while`:

```
randomA = (int)(Math.random()*10+1);
randomB = (int)(Math.random()*10+1)
```